# Can't install or update Ubuntu after using parameter acpi_osi = Linux

Tags: kernel, updates, screen

I recently had an issue with my acer 4736z notebook because I was having a blank screen after booting the OS, then someone told me to use the parameter GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT = "quiet splash acpi_osi = Linux" after quiet splash inside the grub. It worked for me, but since then I can't install a thing or update anything on Linux because it says

```
Removing linux-image-extra-3.5.0-17-generic ...
Examining /etc/kernel/postrm.d .
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools 3.5.0-17-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.5.0-17-generic
update-initramfs: Deleting /boot/initrd.img-3.5.0-17-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub 3.5.0-17-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.5.0-17-generic
/usr/sbin/grub-mkconfig: 11: /etc/default/grub: GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT: not found
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub exited with return code 127
Failed to process /etc/kernel/postrm.d at /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-extra-3.5.0-17-generic.postrm line 328.
dpkg: erro ao processar linux-image-extra-3.5.0-17-generic (--remove):
 sub-processo script post-removal instalado retornou estado de saída de erro 1
Removendo linux-image-3.5.0-17-generic ...
Examining /etc/kernel/postrm.d .
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools 3.5.0-17-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.5.0-17-generic
update-initramfs: Deleting /boot/initrd.img-3.5.0-17-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub 3.5.0-17-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.5.0-17-generic
/usr/sbin/grub-mkconfig: 11: /etc/default/grub: GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT: not found
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub exited with return code 127
Failed to process /etc/kernel/postrm.d at /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-3.5.0-17-generic.postrm line 328.
dpkg: erro ao processar linux-image-3.5.0-17-generic (--remove):
 sub-processo script post-removal instalado retornou estado de saída de erro 1
Erros foram encontrados durante o processamento de:
 linux-image-extra-3.5.0-17-generic
 linux-image-3.5.0-17-generic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I already tried to remove older kernels but it gives me the same message. Do you have a clue about what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

To circumvent this I tried a lot of things, best thing in this situation was for me to use a live cd and reinstall but only formatting /boot partition - warning: you will lose some applications/programs and basic config, BACK UP YOUR CONFIG AND CREATE A LIST OF INSTALLED PROGRAMS FIRST as you will then be able to reinstall programs from the list the config for most of these programs will still be stored in root dir.

Do not format other partitions e.g home, root or swap as you will lose everything else [personal files etc]

Also make sure when doing the reinstallation of the /boot partition to allocate the other partitions accordingly (where your home partition is allocated as the /home partition / partition allocate as such : NOTE: You do NOT need to format /home /swap or /.

I recommend after formatting /boot to login as guest first as this will enable you to run updates and such first - if you log in to your account you may get lock-ups as there are no proper updates and drivers configured etc - Guest first, update and install, reboot and then user account for the rest. hopefully everything will be fine if you check all your partition tables.